# How to make changes to composable when the said composable is clicked on

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose-button, android-compose

I have a composable -

```
@Composable
fun ButtonBar(items: List<ActionButtons>) {
    AppTheme {
        LazyRow(
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 8.dp),
        ) {
            items(items) {
                Box() {
                    TextButton(
                        shape = RectangleShape,
                        onClick = {
                            it.action
                        },
                        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                            contentColor = AppTheme.colors.primary,
                            containerColor = AppTheme.colors.backgroundColor,
                        ),
                    ) {
                        Icon(
                            ImageVector.vectorResource(id = it.buttonIconRes),
                            contentDescription = it.buttonString,
                            modifier = Modifier.size(8.dp),
                            tint = AppTheme.colors.primary,
                        )

                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))

                        Text(
                            text = it.buttonString,
                            style = AppTheme.typography.baseTextAppearanceAction1,
                            color = AppTheme.colors.primary,
                        )
                    }

                    if (it.buttonOnClickAnim != null) {
                        val composition by rememberLottieComposition(
                            spec = LottieCompositionSpec.RawRes(resId = it.buttonOnClickAnim),
                        )

                        LottieAnimation(
                            composition = composition,
                            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterStart).padding(start = 12.dp),
                            iterations = it.animRepeatCount,
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, I wish to show the LottieAnimation only when user taps on the `TextButton` and change the tint of the `Icon` to transparent at the same time.

In the usual XML view, one has access to all the views via their respective ids and make changes to the view when `onClick` is invoked. Like this -

```
buttonItem.buttonOnClickAnim?.let {
                itemBinding.anim.repeatCount = buttonItem.animRepeatCount
                itemBinding.anim.setAnimation(it)
            }

            itemBinding.actionBarButtonText.setOnClickListener {
                if (buttonItem.buttonOnClickAnim != null) {
                    itemBinding.anim.isVisible = true
                    itemBinding.actionBarButtonText.drawableStart?.setTint(itemView.context.getColor(R.color.transparent))
                }

                buttonItem.action.invoke()
            }
```

How do I achieve something similar with Compose?

Comment: let's suppose you have a button and a textView. on tap of the button, change the text of the textView, with compose. would you be able to do that ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody Not really. I don't how to access these "Views" in compose.

Comment: cool, that's fine. but that means you should start by solving my question first (doing some real basics) before applying `LottieAnimation` and other things :) how you considered doing some codelabs or other tutorials on compose ?

Comment: perhaps you can get some ideas [here](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-basics#6)

Comment: I suppose that's what I will have to do. From what I have figured, unlike XML, it is not possible to access "Views" in compose. Only way to update them is to pass new arguments again and reconstruct the composable. correct?

Comment: basically, yes. for what it's worth and the reason why i'm not just giving you an answer, is this mindset and understanding is probably the hardest thing about declarative UI's (flutter, compose). so, this is worth investigating and gaining your own understanding

Comment: Understandable. Thanks :)

Comment: i would strongly suggest just starting with a button and text view and update the text view on click of the button. then, you can look into modifiers (you can add click listeners to them) and then you should be able to solve your own problem

Comment: I recommend you work through the compose tutorials on developer.android.com. They explain clearly how to make these kinds of changes to the UI.

Answer (score 1):

You can use remember to maintain a state that tracks whether the button is tapped.

```
@Composable
fun ButtonBar(items: List<ActionButtons>) {
    AppTheme {
        LazyRow(
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 8.dp),
        ) {
            items(items) { item ->
                var isButtonTapped by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

                Box() {
                    TextButton(
                        shape = RectangleShape,
                        onClick = {
                            // Toggle the state when the button is clicked
                            isButtonTapped = !isButtonTapped

                            // Perform the button action
                            item.action()
                        },
                        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                            contentColor = if (isButtonTapped) Color.Transparent else AppTheme.colors.primary,
                            containerColor = AppTheme.colors.backgroundColor,
                        ),
                    ) {
                        Icon(
                            ImageVector.vectorResource(id = item.buttonIconRes),
                            contentDescription = item.buttonString,
                            modifier = Modifier.size(8.dp),
                            tint = if (isButtonTapped) Color.Transparent else AppTheme.colors.primary,
                        )

                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))

                        Text(
                            text = item.buttonString,
                            style = AppTheme.typography.baseTextAppearanceAction1,
                            color = if (isButtonTapped) Color.Transparent else AppTheme.colors.primary,
                        )
                    }

                    if (isButtonTapped && item.buttonOnClickAnim != null) {
                        val composition by rememberLottieComposition(
                            spec = LottieCompositionSpec.RawRes(resId = item.buttonOnClickAnim),
                        )

                        LottieAnimation(
                            composition = composition,
                            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterStart).padding(start = 12.dp),
                            iterations = item.animRepeatCount,
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```